Delaying a TurnOff of a NMOS with bjt switch

I have two NMOS with common gate signal but I want to delay turn off time of one of them. Like they will turn on at the same time but the one below in the drawing should turn off later. The source on the left is a secondary side of a Flyback and load is basic resistor capacitor load.

I did some research about how to do that with a simple circuit and I find this npn pnp totem pole driver below (sorry for hand drawing). Diode after the gate signal will not let the Cgs of below NMOS discharge so it wont be turned off and the reverse current from flyback should activate the bjt part to operate somehow and turn the below NMOS off after some specific current value (this specific value is not important for now I will play with it) To be honest I couldn't quite understand the circuit and how it works. Moreover I did not understand the reason for the resistors that I put '?', other resistor should be current limiter but what are the '?' ones do exactly. And what happens when we use this pnp npn circuit combination?
Edit : My main idea is when we forget the rest of the circuit, so with the gate turn on signal nmos turns on but can not turn off because there is no discharge path for Cgs right ? But there will be a current that goes back to the flyback secondary winding. So I want bjt circuit that turns on at some return path current (current will make the base voltage more than 1V to turn on npn) to discharge the Cgs of nmos.

Surely, the source is on the left? I think you need to explain what your circuit intends to facilitate. At the moment, it seems that both FETs are in parallel so, turning one off a bit later appears to make the other FET redundant. Hence explain your thinking behind this idea. Have you considered using a simulator?

What you show is not really a totem pole driver. Where did you get that circuit, why do you think it works, have you tried the original circuit as it were?

@Andyaka source on the left yes, my thinking is return current of flyback will turn on the npn and pnp therefore it will discharge the Cgs thus it will turn off NMOS. But I couldnt implement

But, what are you trying to achieve that cannot be done with a single MOSFET? You seem to be trying to solve a problem that doesn't make sense or is invisible to the reader @HubertJo.

@Andyaka Okay I inserted a new screenshot for just the gate capacitor discharge. Forget the rest of the circuit, so with the gate turn on signal nmos turns on but can not turn off because there is no discharge path for Cgs right ? But there will be a current that goes back to the flyback secondary winding. So I want bjt circuit that turns on at some return path current (current will make the base voltage more than 1V to turn on npn) to discharge the Cgs of nmos.
